# Why doesn't get_json_object() work to extract a value from JSON stored in a Hive SQL table?

Tags: sql, json, hive

In my hive table T the field A is a string in json format and A stores a value of `{"c_e_i":"{\"e_c_f\":1}"}`.

I want to get `c_e_i.\"e_c_f\"`

So I used `get_json_object(T.A, '$.c_e_i.\\"e_c_f\\"')` but it doesn't work. what should I do?

I want to get `c_e_i.\"e_c_f\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because `"{\"e_c_f\":1}"` value is a string, not JSON map. The whole thing is not of type `Map<String:Map<String:String>>`, it is `Map<String:String>`

`Map<String:Map<String:String>>` should look like this `{"c_e_i":{"e_c_f":1}}`

And you can extract the string value like this:

```
with T as (
select '{"c_e_i":"{\\\"e_c_f\\\":1}"}' as A 
)

select A as original_str, 
get_json_object(A, '$.c_e_i') as result
from T
```

Result:

```
original_str                  result    

{"c_e_i":"{\"e_c_f\":1}"}     {"e_c_f":1}
```

You see, the result is a correct JSON Map - slashes removed as well because they are interpreted during extract and converted (removed in this case), so you can extract e_c_f from it (apply get_json_object twice):

```
with T as (
select '{"c_e_i":"{\\\"e_c_f\\\":1}"}' as A 
)

select A as original_str, 
get_json_object(get_json_object(A, '$.c_e_i'),'$.e_c_f') as result
from T
```

Result:

```
original_str                result  
{"c_e_i":"{\"e_c_f\":1}"}   1
```

Or remove everything extra from original JSON to make it correct JSON `Map<String:Map<String:String>>` then extract:

```
with T as (
select '{"c_e_i":"{\\\"e_c_f\\\":1}"}' as A 
)

select A as original_str, 
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(A, '\\\\"','"'), '"\\{','\\{'),'"\\}','\\}') as correct_JSON, --remove slashes and remove doublequotes before { and after }  
get_json_object(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(A, '\\\\"','"'), '"\\{','\\{'),'"\\}','\\}'), '$.c_e_i.e_c_f') as result
```

Result:

```
original_str                    correct_json           result   
{"c_e_i":"{\"e_c_f\":1}"}      {"c_e_i":{"e_c_f":1}}    1
```

Comment: I can't believe I never found out that the value is a string, I'm going crazy. you're really awesome, I adore you

Comment: I just found a much simpler solution that I tried that works:get_json_object(get_json_object(T.A, '$.c_e_i'),'$.e_c_f')

Comment: Yep, the second script